# Non idempotent SQL command with OrientDB JDBC Driver

Tags: sql, nosql, orientdb, idempotent

**Hello,
I'm facing an issue while using the JDBC driver to connect to a Plocal Orient DB.
Here is my code:**

```
            Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put("user", this.user);
    info.put("password", this.pwd);
    java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver());

    Connection conn = (OrientJdbcConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, info);

    String sql = "insert into personne (name) values(?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, "test recuperation RID par jdbc");

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    ...
```

**And here the exception stack;**

Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Cannot execute non idempotent command
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.executeCommand(OStorageEmbedded.java:90)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.command(OStorageEmbedded.java:85)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:69)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:82)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:29)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.query(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:505)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.query(ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.java:188)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(OrientJdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.octopus.dao.jeudonnees.impl.JdbcJeuDonneesDAO.create(JdbcJeuDonneesDAO.java:39)
    at org.octopus.dao.jeudonnees.impl.JdbcJeuDonneesDAO.create(JdbcJeuDonneesDAO.java:1)
    at org.octopus.tests.tests.main(tests.java:23)

**It seems like it's not possible to run non idempotent commands using the Orient JDBC Driver.
Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to call an insert with JDBC is by using .executeUpdate():

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/